# IOS Submitted App to the AppStore Rejected

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

I have submitted my app to the appstore, but it was rejected.

This is my error when my app was rejected.

How can I fix this error.
[image]

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score 2):

You have to take care of below things for your app to overcome rejection 14.3 -

- Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content
- Use moderators to flag and remove inappropriate content and offensive users
- Users need a mechanism to flag objectionable content and report users generating this content
- Developer must act on objectionable content reports within 24 hours by removing the content and ejecting the user who provided the offending content
- Developer needs a method for ejecting users who violate the terms of the EULA

Comment: I don't know about Require that users agree to terms (EULA) and these terms must make it clear that there is no tolerance for objectionable content.

Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, you should put legal terms & condition to use this app in itunes

Comment: Goto Itunes connect -> Select Your app -> Select Version -> License Agreement Edit (Apple's Standard License Agreement) . You can find it just below App ID , Rating etc.

Comment: After I had chosen (Apple's Standard License Agreement) -> Done.
After that, I will re-submit my app to the appstore???

Comment: No Do you have make provision for User delete and content remove

Comment: I don't know about this. You can help me, please.

Comment: When user post / send message /image for others user then other user should be to block this content , like facebook

Comment: Yes, you have change your code and implement a mechanism, so that user can raise flag for offensive content